# Get one item out of a API response?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I try to call a web endpoint (clk.example-
api.com/berlin/clk/bikes/eBike20131127000a). That webpoint response with a JSON:

```
{
 "geo": {

     "latitude": 52.520278,
     "longitude": 13.415712
 },
 "connection": {
     "connected": false,
     "since": "2017-06-20T14:55:15.280Z"
 },
 "mileage": 29382,
 "vin": "eBike20131127000a",
 "fuelLevel": 46,
 "batteryLevel": 5.424346,
 "light": false,
 "charging": false,
 "pedalForce": 0,
 "speed": 0,
 "batteryVoltageBike": 48742
}
```

My code I writed for this is:

```
function httpGet(myData, callback) {
  console.log("got to the http function"); 

// Update these options with the details of the web service you would like 
to call
var options = {
//the endpoint i call for example: 
//clk.example-api.com/berlin/clk/bikes/eBike20131127000a

    host: 'clk.example-api.com',
    path: '/berlin/clk/bikes/' + encodeURIComponent(myData),
    method: 'GET'
};


var req = http.request(options, res => {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    var returnData = "";


    res.on('data', chunk => {
        returnData = returnData + chunk;
    });


    res.on('end', () => {
        // we have now received the raw return data in the returnData 
variable.
        // We can see it in the log output via:
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(returnData))
        // we may need to parse through it to extract the needed data
        console.log(returnData);
        callback(returnData);  // this will execute whatever function the 
caller defined, with one argument
    });


});
req.end();
}
```

I actually want the Item fuelLevel storing into returnData. Maybe there is one who can help me out of this situation. I have no glue how todo.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example uses `request` module, a really common module (25million downloads in the last month) used for api calls within node.

You will need to install request `npm install request`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

```
var request = require('request');

function httpGet(myData, callback) {

    request('http://www.mocky.io/v2/' + encodeURIComponent(myData), function (error, response, body) {

        if (error) {
            return callback(error);
        }

        var info = JSON.parse(body);

        const fuelLevel = info.fuelLevel;

        callback(null, fuelLevel);

    });

}

function completed(err, data){
    if (err){
        console.log(err)
    }
    console.log(data);
}

httpGet('594bbf6e1200004111424b7d', completed)
```

Comment: if I use https instead of http I have to install https...right?!
and if I try this solution ...I get null :(

Comment: no the url can be https or http, its using the request module, it does not care.  tweaked the answers to https

Comment: ok so i have not to install node_modules for http and or https?! ...and can you even guess why i get null :(

Comment: You would never need to install modules for `http` or `https` they come as part of Node - they are native.
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Comment: get null where?

Comment: oh ok thx for that hint :) 
If log via console I can find out, that after I reached the httpGet() nothing is happens...

Comment: I have updated the example with a real mocked api endpoint returning the data structure you delcared in your question.  Also tweaked the script a bit so there is an example of how to run it.  The above code when ran always console.logs 46